# Twitter API PHP Get latest tweets not authenticating

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm using this peice of code to try and get all my latest tweets for printing on my site but it's returning an error about being not authenticated. I've created an app in the Dev section and get my consumer and OAuth keys, and added them in the right place in the code.

```
    <?php
        function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
            $r = array();
        ksort($params);
        foreach($params as $key=>$value){
            $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
        }
        return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
        }

        function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
        $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
        $values = array();
        foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
            $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
        $r .= implode(', ', $values);
        return $r;
        }

        $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jameskrawczyk";
        $oauth_access_token = "SECURITY";
        $oauth_access_token_secret = "SECURITY";
        $consumer_key = "SECURITY";
        $consumer_secret = "SECURITY";

        $oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                    'oauth_nonce' => time(),
                    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                    'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
                    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                    'oauth_version' => '1.0');



        $base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
        $composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' .     rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
        $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
        $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;



        $header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
        $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                      //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                      CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);



        $feed = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
        $json = curl_exec($feed);
        curl_close($feed);
        $twitter_data = json_decode($json, true);
        foreach ($twitter_data as $elem)
        {
          print_r($elem);
          echo '<br>';
        }
```

Error returned on page

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [message] => Could not authenticate you [code] => 32 ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer seemed to be that the line

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jameskrawczyk";
```

should not have the `?screen_name=jameskrawczyk` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to use an library to get data from twitter
>   "themattharris" is a good and famous library download it from [here](https://github.com/themattharris)

Comment: According to their API 1.1 info you can still use it it's just no preferred. They even give examples on how to use it

Comment: Please up vote to my Answer I am no longer allowed to ask question due to down vote